# Java: Is there any advantage to calling a constructor in main like this?

Tags: java, constructor, program-entry-point

In the book "Sams Teach Yourself Java", the author often writes a bunch of code in a constructor and puts the main block outside of it and then calls the constructor inside the main block. Is there any advantage to doing this instead of writing the code inside the main block as some do?

Example:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Configurator {

Configurator() {
    try {
        // load the properties file
        File configFile = new File("program.properties");
        FileInputStream inStream = new
        FileInputStream(configFile);
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.load(inStream);
        // create a new property
        Date current = new Date();
        config.setProperty("runtime", current.toString());
        // save the properties file
        FileOutputStream outStream = new
        FileOutputStream(configFile);
        config.store(outStream, "Properties settings");
        inStream.close();
        config.list(System.out);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("IO error " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    Configurator con = new Configurator();
}
```

}

Comment: For this small toy program, there really is no advantage. But for most all other programs that are more than just trivial, the main method should be very small, and most code work should be done in the instance domain, not the static domain.

Comment: He also uses pretty nice formatting. I would not read that book.

Comment: This might be the author's aversion to using `static`. As soon as you need more than one method working with the same data, you have to declare class data members. If you don't create an object instance, everything would need to be declared `static` (and give a confusing error if you forgot).

Comment: Doing all that work in a constructor, swallowing exceptions, not closing streams, is bad practice. I wouldn't read that book either.

Comment: Is there any book you would recommend that I should read instead? @JBNizet

Comment: Unfortunately, I've started learning Java in 1997. So I've stopped reading introductory Java books for a loooong time. I've been told that *Thinking in Java*, by Bruce Eckel, was a good one.

Comment: Yeah, it's usually a bad idea to put "actual function" in a constructor, vs (in this case) putting it in `main` or in a `doit` instance method.  No real biggie for a "toy" program, but no real point in putting the code in the constructor, either.

Comment: (For a "toy", my usual strategy is to create an instance named `me` and then use `me.` to qualify references in `main`.  In the rare cases that that gets cumbersome I'm move the logic to the `doit` instance method.)

Comment: Indeed, not the best book. I suggest the [Head First Java](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfjava/) book and the Java Tutorial available on the web from Oracle. After that, the Eckel book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the quality of the constructor goes, there are other answers/comments which have explained why this is a bad idea. Regarding specifically placing all of your code into a constructor rather than directly in `main`, it has benefit when it comes to automated testing and portability.

Moving all code into a constructor allows that code to be tested by automated testing frameworks much more easily than testing `main`. In addition by placing your entire app inside a class without a main you allow it to be plucked and used in other applications.

Comment: Of course, there's nothing to prevent another application from invoking your `main`.

Comment: @HotLicks true, it's more about preference than capability. The interface for `main` is fixed so I always like to keep the application and `main` pretty separate.

Answer (score 3):

That book is quite notorious for being quite bad. But there is a heck of a lot fo code in that constructor, constructors are inteded to 'construct' an object, such as setting values of the object etc. Not perform so many tasks, create methods in the class that the constructor can call on instead.

Answer (score 0):

For example, the main is a static method and it wants only static variables, so it's not good write a great amount of code in.